# React Native Gradle assembleDebug takes an hour

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have a basically unmodified react native project that takes almost an hour to build. It was taking 15 minutes until I made a few small tweaks (which were supposed to speed things up) and now it takes an hour. I've included two custom modules (`react-native-webrtc` and `react-native-nodejs-mobile`). I did a build scan and it just says the main gradle files are the culprits. Most things take seconds.

```
app/build.gradle    Script  5m 57.428s  (7m 36.999s total)  Applied to 1 project    3 tasks created 
/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle    Script  3m 52.452s      Applied to 2 projects       
settings.gradle Script  3m 0.513s   (5m 18.035s total)  Applied to 1 project
```

`assembleRelease` took an hour before I made any changes. I'm now working on getting assembleDebug back to 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason, but I was running a docker container on a MacOS host and the entire repo was on the host so all the file requests had to run over the network file share. I think this is probably what the problem was. Once I installed Android Studio directly on my Mac, using the instructions on the react native website, it now takes several minutes to complete.